# What is the place where Jesus went after death?

Tags: hell

After Jesus died, he went to the place of the Dead.
1 Peter 8:19-20

> **19** After being made alive, he went and made proclamation to the imprisoned spirits— **20** to those who were disobedient long ago when God waited patiently in the days of Noah while the ark was being built. In it only a few people, eight in all, were saved through water,

If possible, I'd like an answer covering the following aspects:

1. What is this place ?
2. Is it Sheol/Hades?
3. Does it still exist now?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Did Jesus spend time in Hell between the crucifixion and resurrection?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/488/69)

Comment: probable duplicate of [Where was Jesus during the period from His death to resurruction?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/8579/69)