# Where did Jesus go after he died at the cross?

Tags: easter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Did Jesus spend time in Hell between the crucifixion and resurrection?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/488/did-jesus-spend-time-in-hell-between-the-crucifixion-and-resurrection)

In the dutch traditional creed, is written that Jesus went down to hell. And sometimes people say Jesus overcame the grave, the death or hell.

But also, Jesus says to the thief next to him at the cross that he will be in paradise with him today.

I'm wondering, where was Jesus' soul/spirit or whatever when his body was in the grave?