# Can we visit loved ones in Hell?

Tags: biblical-basis, heaven, hell

According to an answer on this site, we can still be happy while knowing that people are in Hell and suffering. Growing up, they've always told us that the Bible says that when we enter Heaven, we are given everything we have and/or could ever want.

What if I wanted to visit a loved on in who was sent to Hell? Is there any scriptural evidence that states, or suggests that we will be allowed to visit people in Hell?

Comment: In the story of the rich man and Lazarus, there was a great chasm that separated Lazarus from the rich man, and no one was able to pass from one side to the other.

Comment: @Narnian thank you for your input! Now that you've mentioned it, I also remember reading that somewhere. Now, I also remember reading somewhere that Satan is able to visit God with the other Angels. That Satan found a way to enter and leave Hell. If Heaven and Hell were separated, how could Satan get to/from Heaven and Hell? And if Satan can, is it possible that others can, too?

Comment: @user-12506 asking for scriptural evidence and tagging Catholocism belies a lack of understanding of how Catholicism deals with the scriptures. Please be mindful of this going forward. If you're asking about what the bible says, use [tag:biblical-basis] if you want to know what the Catholic doctrine is use [tag:catholicism]

Comment: Yeah, that's the story of Job.  Satan and the demons are not currently confined to hell, as he roams around like a roaring lion, seeking someone to devour.  However, it seems that humans are, indeed, confined to hell or heaven after they die.  One day Satan and the demons will be confined to hell--just not yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a Biblical basis for the belief that a living person may visit heaven or hell?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/16390/is-there-a-biblical-basis-for-the-belief-that-a-living-person-may-visit-heaven-o)

Answer (score 7):

The story of [The Rich Man and Lazarus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_man_and_Lazarus), found in [Luke 16:19-31](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke+16%3A19-31&version=NIV) tell us it is impossible to visit others in Hell:

> 'And besides all this, between us and you a great chasm has been set in place, so that those who want to go from here to you cannot, nor can anyone cross over from there to us.’

Comment: I cringe every time I see this passage used because it is so commonly used to support something it does not say, but in this case I think the usage is appropriate! No visitation.

Comment: @Caleb: You have me curious now... how have you seen it (ab)used?